# Who is photographer Scott Mead?

Tags: photographer

Is anyone familiar with the photographer Scott Mead? Does he have any exhibitions?
I heard his name a few days ago but I haven't heard of him before.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Mead is primarily known in the world of investment banking. He has a Bachelor's degree from *Harvard* (1977), a masters from *Emmanuel College, Cambridge* (1979), and holds a Juris Doctor from the University of Pennsylvania Law School (1982). He started his career with First Boston Corporation. From 1986 until 2003 he worked for Goldman-Sachs, first in New York and then in London. He was a partner and managing director when he left to co-found Richmond Park Partners.

While an undergraduate at Harvard Mead studied photography under William Eggleston when he spent a year as a visiting professor at Harvard. After leaving his investment banking career, Mead rededicated himself to photography. Some of his early works were sold at a solo show in London in 2010 and the proceeds donated to charity. He has had photographs selected for the *Royal Academy Summer Exhibition* in 2011, 2012, and 2013. According to his [photography web site](http://scottmeadphotography.co.uk/exhibitions/) the only piece currently on public display is at the 2013 *Summer Exhibition*. He plans to open another solo exhibition of his more recent work in the future.

http://scottmeadphotography.co.uk/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Mead

Answer (score 0):

I looked a bit on the net and I found some Info also on http://www.scottmead.org/